# Does CLOS is a weakness in Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp, clos

What I want to mean is if CLOS is a bad practice to the Lisp functional programming way?

Comment: Your question is a bit too brief to give a full answer to. Reading between the words, I've answered the question I think you're asking, but it would be good if you could flesh the question out a bit more, expanding on what parts of CLOS and why you believe Common Lisp is a FP language.

Answer (score 5):

Common Lisp is not a "functional programming" language, it is a "multi-paradigm" programmable programming language.

CLOS is less of a bar to readable code than the PROG special form is. Both are useful, in their niches. Hopefully the niche of CLOS is larger than that of PROG.